# Trying to publish 'GeekQuiz' app to azure, database not transferring over?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2015

I've changed the `TriviaDatabseInitializer` to be declared as such:

```
public class TriviaDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TriviaContext>
```

Running locally everything works fine, running on the Azure site after publishing (with the publish config) works except none of the data from the database loads.

I suspect this is because there is no database the app is connecting to. I've tried googling the problem but haven't come across anything useful, probably because I don't actually know what I should be googling for.

Comment: Your question contradicts itself, but maybe we can clean it up a bit and get to what your real problem is.  `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` is a *terrible* idea in production, especially on Azure, since it completely deletes and recreates an empty database every time the app is restarted (which happens a lot on azure). This implies that when the app starts up, there wouldn't be any data from the database.

Comment: Ah yes I'm just doing it as a test, I've overriden the 'Seed' function which creates several entries for the database.

Comment: Running locally the seed function is called everytime I run the web app for the first time so I thought it would just work on azure which is why I think it just doesn't know what database to seed on azure..

Comment: did you verify that the database being supplied in your Publish settings is a valid azure database?

Comment: Also, it is *highly* recommended to use Migrations instead of the simple database initializers when working with azure.

Comment: hmm actually under 'Publish Web' in the preview tab it says 'No databases are selected to publish': http://i.imgur.com/YG1cx3y.png

Comment: ah ok maybe I'll look into using migrations then.

Comment: you posted the preview tab, what databases are selected on the settings tab? (left side options)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96548/discussion-between-soshiki-and-claies).

Comment: I posted a few troubleshooting ideas to that chat transcript for you to review when you have time, good luck!